# ViewController loaded in the Background after creating it from MapKit (didSelectAnnotationView)

Tags: ios5, uiviewcontroller, mapkit

I'm trying to create from the delegate method didSelectAnnotationView a ViewController.
I've got following Code:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    DestinationViewController *destinationViewController = [[DestinationViewController alloc] init];
    NSNumber *mynumberId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    destinationViewController.mynumberId = mynumberId;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:destinationViewController animated:YES];
}
```

After I tap on a Annotation I'm seeing just a black ViewController Screen with the Navigation Bar. But the Log tells me that everything is loaded correctly. So it seems like my Destination ViewController is somewhere in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your VC from a Nib, you need to use initWithNibName: rather than just init.

If you load the view programmatically, you need to check your viewDidLoad method.

It is not a mapKit issue, but you are not loading your VC and its view the way you should.

Comment: I'm using Storyboards. I've found the solution for my Problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've researched on the Apple Developer Site and found the answer for my question. I'm using Storyboards, and here the code snippet from Apple:

```
- (IBAction)presentSpecialViewController:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    SpecialViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SpecialViewController"];

    // configure the new view controller explicitly here.

    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

and here the Link where you can find more Info about View Controller Programming:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html